# Javascript .play() function works on all browsers but mobile ones?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, safari

Javascript sound does not work on Iphone or android in this page: http://www.webalice.it/i4mattera/lol/jungle/minimal_crossjungle/crossjungle.htm if you press the button (own blue), after 5 seconds a sound is played in chrome, firefox and safari on MAC but NOT on safari mobile (IPHONE) or android.

Why is that?

Additional information: The function ".play()" works fine on safari mobile, as you can see on this example: http://www.webalice.it/i4mattera/lol/jungle/javascriptsound_separate/

How is it possible that sound works (on IOS safari and android) in the last example but does not in the former? The command to play audio is the same!

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MMMMhhhhhhkay I did it.
I post the solution here, in case anyone needs it (I doubt it, seeing the number of answers).
The thing is in the main function I had to use the "load" function to get the sound ready to play.

In the main I added something like:
obsound=document.getElementById('obsound');
obsound.load();

then i call .play() function when the timer ends.